# VBA to copy text from IE to Excel

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vbscript, copy

Can anyone help me with a simple Visual Basic script which copies the field qwidget_lastsale from the following site to an excel sheet?

http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/abt/recommendations

I have been trying to modify existing scripts, but just cannot seem to make it work. So far I can open the site and excel, but cannot copy the field.

I would like to have the copy script after this:

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
WebSite = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/abt/recommendations"
with objExplorer
.Navigate2 WebSite
.left=5
.top=5
.height=1100
.width=700
.AddressBar = 0
.Visible = 1
.ToolBar = 0
.StatusBar = 1
WScript.Sleep 1000
Set objIE = Nothing
end with

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xl.Application.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\user\Documents\testauto.xlsx"
xl.Application.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DOM manipulation, and **NOT** release your `objExplorer` from memory so soon:

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

WebSite = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/abt/recommendations"
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Long = 4

With objExplorer
    .Navigate2 WebSite
    .Left=5
    .Top=5
    .Height=1100
    .Width=700
    .AddressBar = 0
    .Visible = 1
    .ToolBar = 0
    .StatusBar = 1
    '//WScript.Sleep 1000
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        WScript.Sleep 1000
    Loop
    '//Set objIE = Nothing (your variable isn't called 'objIE' anyway?)
End With

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Visible = True

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\testauto.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") '// Change name of sheet as required

ws.Range("A1").Value = objExplorer.Document.getElementById("qwidget_lastsale").Value

'// Rest of code....
'// ...

'// NOW clear down your variables.
objExplorer.Quit

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
xl.Quit

Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing
Set objExplorer = Nothing
```

---

Also, as you can see above I changed a couple of things:

- Internet Explorer has a [`READYSTATE` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268229(v=vs.85).aspx) that returns a `Long`. You can test this to see if the page has loaded rather than sleeping for 1 sec and hoping for the best...
- When you create an instance of Excel using `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` the object returned *is* the application object - no need to reference it again. You'll notice I took those out.
- When interacting with Excel workbooks, it's best to use variables for `Application`, `Workbook` and `Worksheet` objects separately and work with this. This ensures you're always on the sheet you *intend* to be and that you're closing the *right* workbook at the *right* time.
- Code indentation is your friend - it makes everything much easier to read and follow.

Comment: Thanks for all your tips and suggestions. I would like to continue with Macro Mans suggestion, but I get an error: Object doesn't support this property or method 'objExplorer.Document.getElementByID(...).Value. Code 800A01B6. Could I have selected the wrong element on the page, or why is it not supported?

Comment: I managed to get it working with the above suggestion using .innerText instead of .Value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Function Read(URL)

     Set ie = Wscript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

     Set objFSO = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

     ie.Navigate(URL) 

     ie.Visible = 1

      DO WHILE ie.busy

         wscript.sleep 100

      LOOP

  Data = ie.document.documentElement.innertext 

  Msgbox(Data)

  sp = Split(Data," ")

  b  = ubound(sp)

  Msgbox(b)

For i=0 to b

    Msgbox(sp(i))

Next



selectexcel=inputbox("Enter the location","Location of the excel file(Xls/xlsx)","Enter your path here !")

        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(selectexcel)

        objExcel.visible=True

        rowCount=objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.count
        colCount=objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.count


        For i=1 to  b Step 1

           For j=1 to 1 Step 1

              objExcel.Cells(i,j).Value=sp(i)

              k=k+1

           Next

       Next       

End Function

Read "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/abt/recommendations"

Set ie = Nothing
```

Comment: in this code i have splited the data in the website by " " character